# Displaying an Image from a Binary Stream - Angular 10

Tags: angular, image, binary, uri, media-type

I have an issue rendering an image to a Browser when retrieving that image from a REST endpoint.  I perform a GET to the endpoint and am streamed a binary representation of the image.  I cannot get this image to render on the browser.

I have read every Stack Overflow posting I can find on this topic and have read a dozen other articles.  I have tried to implement the various recommendations and combinations of recommendations, but have not been successful in displaying this image on the browser.  It is important to note that, if I use Postman to call this REST endpoint, the image renders just fine in Postman.

I will try to provide more detail in a concise manner.

Here is a code snippet from the REST endpoint.  This will give you a sense of what I am working with...

```
final StreamingOutput fileStream = output -> {
     output.write(photo.getData());
     output.flush();
};
```

Here is an example output from this endpoint...

```
����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u0000�\u0000\t\u0006\u0007\u0013\u0013\u0012\u0015\u0013\u0012\u0012\u0015\u0015\u0015\u0016\u0015\u0017\u0015\u0016\u0015\u0015\u0015\u0017\u0015\u0016\u0015\u0015\u0016\u0015\u0016\u0018\u0015\u0015\u0015\u0015\u0018\u001d( \u0018\u001a%\u001d\u0015\u0015!1!%)+...\u0017\u001f383-7(-.+\u0001\n\n\n\u000e\r\u000e\u001a\u0010\u0010\u001a-%\u001f%--------------------------------------------------��\u0000\u0011\b\u0000�\u0001\u0013\u0003\u0001\u0011\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0001\u0003\u0011\u0001��\u0000\u001b\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0005\u0002\u0003\u0006\u0001\u0000\u0007��\u0000=\u0010\u0000\u0001\u0004\u0000\u0004\u0003\u0006\u0003\u0007\u0003\u0002\u0006\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0003\u0011\u0004\u0012!1\u0005AQ\u0013\"aq��\u00062�BR�����\u0014#�3r\u0007\u0015bs��\u0016$D��\u0000\u001b\u0001\u0000\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0000\u0005\u0006\u0007��\u00004\u0011\u0000\u0002\u0002\u0001\u0004\u0001\u0002\u0004\u0004\u0005\u0004\u0003\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0011\u0003\u0004\u0012!1A\u0005Q\u0013\"aq2���\u0014����#BR�\u0006C�\u0015��\u0000\f\u0003\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0003\u0011\u0000?\u0000\u000b-/52,�UB�!\u0013���4qC��4\u0014J9iEK��Dr*�\u000e\u001d\u0003\u0015T�cL4i�l4ǥ�\\��f̚[���ݦPdi\u001d~��K\u0016xO��e/pq\u0003^h�V|�%�e-��\u0005ˎ\t��ߕ���\u0011�s\u0017�a����Ӯ��׸\u0014���St6�S�x���Ԅ���ǂӾ�j�8��\u0010F>\u0000\u0000&��Vk�\u0019���\u001e׵č��,���:w�l6� ��\r��ǒ�^�2o�Hv\u0003��,}f\u0007Cc.�zh�\u0007�*U\b�Ь%�q\u000b��\u0003�\u000fÒ�lP��S��@ؼh\u0001\u0017\u0014 �\u0013�I�\rBɧ%\u001aH'pxl��R)\u0001���x32�P�����b88o�\u0002��`�B(k��c\n\r�s#\u0015�U�!X\u0004�W��\t�e�b��E1�L[ñg;�\f��X5\u000b��oN<\u001a\u001c�\u0017���A��Y\\�H*9Z\u0002Շ\u0013|��6�\u001cfQf�����_�G,\\]1�\"��\u001e�\u000b^�gq1�B���8���\u0016%\u0013ȜR\u0012 �����a \u0014hb�Ϋ�#�\u0003I�\u0012�\u001b}\u000f\bJ�X�\u000e�NFx�i�#\bX�\t����\u0007)\u001a�9�,Z�1��\u001e%�\u0015�\u0013��l�n�:�{N�j�K�Öx��}���~�6���T\u0016\u0006i\u0018\u0005�]d�&ڦ\bb��撲2��\u001d�\b�����\u0004~%Y�\u0019Ur�\u0000o�.�&G�\r�*�q���%\u001aȦ�\b�r��F9�k�$h�F�\u0004\u001dG��䔣[�x�Ur\u0014�0�ۤ�\u001c)�\u001a\u0000��^I>/�V\u0013��CgO�\u000b�g�ݲR�++��n�����X�G40�\u001b��\u0019L\u0002�!)7��\u0000P�pӅ\u0010ӯ�h΄h�aq\"�*�\"\u0010��Zt�\u0005.z6\u0014BS\\�r:\u0003)t�3v+\u0015�Xt��\u0015�J\u001b7*5i����\u0015�\u001a��]��y:�$�\u001a��\u001a�\n�\u0010ց�5]6�\u001c�y\u0015���t\u000fɚ�B�-4`�\u001e��&���B�0�!����ؖ�Zu�i�\u001cV���5�8\u0017���h\r ��\u0015��\u0017\f��0�\u0004\u0018�h�<X�\u00149ʛ��\u000b4�I��\u001b�Q�\u0018�j��Ő?T��0<xEM�j�-N�~ߊ�\u0019���\fq-4\\W�IG�\u001b]�u�A֎�d\u001f��r��h�Ó��>�\u001d�\u001cc�젗\u0002\t֭����r���M6/��\u0012J_O#��4�,�]k`�˙����K�\u0012v&��1�y�/!�\u001d.|����@=�n�\u000f$��#�\u0012Rm�a0��F�:\u0001���2�㣣\u0007&\u001b.=���\u0000]��?����K���=��yԓd�N�}��7'l��-��\u0001\u0000�\u0017��O��lyZj�b� S\u001a�h\u001bV��x%J��gl\u0019�\u0005T�`\u0018��+�l\u0018��71�^\u0017\u0002Jd:\rg\u000fTJ��T8ZO�V›\u0015!��V�cv��\u0014��E�p3�Q�\u0001\u0003\"�\u0015��\u0010��N�\u0004߀�#��W\u0017\u0005�U\u0002+�AZ)\u001cһe�~!<N˗3y\u0015\u0019�=�G���Q���Hc�\u0007\u001d\u001c9u�Y!��'�r��v�DѾ!.\rΉ��5o1[��\t���{\u0019�.y1n���K���Q��i�\"Lc\u0011\u0000�b��*�H��A\u0018.\u0016���9[˩�\u000b\u0006}d1���\f\u001b�\u001a�\f$8�\\@\u001e�\u0014!�,��%A\\�JN\u0012�/�vb\rSGwm�^�pǹ3��z3�\u0015<������Z�h�5խ�`}���EtoZ\f8�\u0000\n���\u0011���\u000bE��A-$\u0011�;(d��\u0000\r\u001e~�4��T�\u001dp\u001e\u001d�����\f��\u0006g�\u0003��=6�;�hśW,�)>���';d��_�֮i\u000f#���]\u0018�+i�\u00002<IW�i��\u000b31�<;N�n47'd�\u0014�T�`G\u001b�\u0014�\"\r�����{�^\u001b�m�\u0015��ƭ'�e��n5_\u000b�/�q�����\u0017@y\u0004��&�*����\u0018�\u0000�'�r1q\u0001ҽ�g) O�\u0000\u001aӾwK�_�1�\u0007\r�諏P��x��A�$剹/j����\u00131j>}���Ԏ'\u0014<�>\u0006@�*\u0012��c��'�%\":�B�B%PC�T�B��b(�a\r��\u0012\u0005�0\u001eK���X�Vu��\u000emFQ�Ydp%؅e�\u0000��\u0005�\u0010)sA\u0005��y\u0015��+�;\u0004x$Q^J�{�~8��t2��Mk�z�Y(�C�Po\u0011��l�\ri\"�#j:���L\u0013��\t��\u001a�\\�HQ&1��œK9\rJdq,'\n��N[7��\u0017���\u0005�1~��F�\u000e\u0016.�_��\u0001`�\u0016����b��\u0011\u0013l���ޞ'�mǎ�5���˃;�Y<���r\u0017�������R�!��t����tn���Y\f����Q���vD��\n\u001f��'�4y��,��ǰȹ!P��n\u0018���.GQ�\u001a� <����7]\u001a�j\u00148���3x_�'��\u0000fx�(P\u0015@6�\u0011\\�\u0011j���=�\u0012�2-�1�K\u0015 ��=��Ü��9\u001b�l�]\u000e�n\u0018�j���'��\u0000�(5�=�>��#�|�0����BQ6|�\f�\u0015�E7\u0001%�q�x{N���|\u0013���������J���c������\u0000r���3‥j�62\u0005#U�\\��v\u0012JZ���\u001eॵ�%,h�aTFΌ:\u0004�DQ&LR��I��yi+`\u0017b��BlV\u0000��\u0006؍�\u0012\u0014-��\u001926\u0014�n�%e\u0013%Hm*������$f�o>�_\ne��4x\u001f�Z#hx�\u0001GN�-�/\u001c�Ķr���\u000bfi&���O,q�t�J�\u0003t\u0003^g���u\u001a���G���l�7�Y�?u(E.��H��\u001fy�\u0017rhּ��Xf�~d:����vgn�\u0018AAR\u000b\b�\f��\t�\u001aE0\f \n�!�}\u0004�:D�[E�=��\u0000��� �/��\r������p��MQ\u001e?��.�Qo��G�k��|�����\b\u0004\u0003Uty����\u0019\u0013H�<>��cm;R\u0013\u00168\u001a�2�\u0005kg]z�W�|D�G������\u0000�\u001eb4��]\u0017�(�_��-�7\fa���Hz��Z�q�����8��\u00168��4;��[\u000eK�?\u0007羻��\u0019~$z����R�\t�\u00100�ʊ\\������\u0005b1�IEhE\u00071N�p�\u0007�&�9\u0013h�h�}\u0000�:�p,�J�+\u0004�#��\u0006T�+ �\u0014�D�ք6���\u001d��:d\\�9}ӥ�\u0006�K������QX�r�ma2�u��W�,�=+2�\u000b$��\u0001�ԯ?6<�^�t/,\u000b\u0015������-\u001aNs�A�T�U�4�����z��c�(��~\u0006;�Ti.�cx�A�l*(�Э\u0017�+�Z&�Ҥ\u0006H�6�u!�\u001f3���VJ��7�\u0003�8��Ō �:n�f��1�)sˍ���X�\u0014�^�}D�\u0019̿\u001e`�G2A����-�y\\\u0011�\u001f�%=\u0016?���TXK�hr-�e��7v�m�\u0006��2_1S��6@u\u001a���A�4FW�4\\6P{�G��f�����m#ςP]���9���V�t��\u0002\u001bB�نU�T�e���И�\u0019��\u001a8g\f�Eh%�%�h�\tZ8��IȬ\u0012v.\u0011��\u0012؍\u0014�&R\u0005\u0016F�Π���\u0019 �\u0010��\u0011|R�e���c~��\\\u0019�^�\u001f�>��\u001a\r�(�m1�q2�A\u0005\n�}��r\u0011�I\u001c8���F;�Z\r�\u0019\u001cK�]١B��I��T�憈��;;{&��6\u001c�9���f�\u0000�߄j���b�\u000b#dM\u0011\u001bm^m˴��뢆_�)��AﲼmD��b~.�_}\u0000\u001e��\u0000k^���\u001f�Q�C��l\u0018�\u0003kK��?e�Y�N\u0016+��\u0012tLOkO�DH\u0010\u001a2E��\u0002�c\f\u001e04�iJpo�sN\u001b~fj0�e\u0016�\u000fT�߇��ߪ�s�7�\u001c��\u001e>���S4y\b CA<x\u001d\u0001��:e\u0010�;)VO��0�X@�\u001a\u001c��h�� \u0002�0)X�\u0014NmI��\u001b�J-\u0002�\u0012[\u0005\u0016D�w\rA152c$\u0015�4\u0012v\b�e!\u000bfO�>&]�lt4��)\u001aڤ(\u001f\u000f���\"���\u0014\u000eM�0�� #�=R(d\u0002S����NL\fo�b��lu�j\u0002X{J\r���\u0018�\u0016���0�]��h<����'�}Y�\u0014R[�g�n\fi$�5'��p\b��*�\u0002Ș5���o�~+4��9xg�\u0017��7\"q��(�\"�P.7z�}\u0016�IEQ���\u0014qcX��T\u0000p�]v���ۋQY5]�\u001b\u0011\u0007a\u0007Uہ,qH\u0006f����E\\{d�<mf�&8���d���q���\u0010K�|n�U�$��0�\u0017��ٚ�+��\u0010�&(�U$&\rL���}?�>��\u001bf)����7�\u000b̞9c{e�?�6�\u00169/������\u0000G�m3T�1!n+db�B�\rU�0^\u001f�\u0013�\u001aW\u0000��#8�\u0001J��\u001aR4+D\u001e\u0012�-\u00149�6�GZ\u0017m\tc\u0013$\u0014-㯓!���Z1Q�\u001bI\u0019�\u0016$e ��ʦTq�\u001aj���k�r�Q�M;�U\u0004�1ڜ��>\u001c:��#c\\$*M���\u0018а\u0016�wb�p���K�F���\u001c�UqA]��c���>%�3������ӗ/eV���goj�\t8�<\u0000I�l�ϥ�\r�i5�!�m�`������`�\u001dH�3s�Y櫮��]�q/��z4�\u0016'\u001b�4�t\u0016MV8��#?.+O\u0013^���jQ��۠q:v\u0007\"�)��\u0002r��n֊V\r͢��O-�F�!�\u0014d�\u0006\u001c9�;)sX�\\Z2�Gt�������g����k��<O��\u0007��of���� �G��x�\u0012�|U�Y�#y\u001e�v\u000eo6�,�S�1�'\u001b�'ٰ��K\u001bea��\u0007\u0003�\u001f\u0010�i�\u0016�&\u0001�+��aT�Z�\u0010�\u0018Ns\u001aE\u0012V)c�Ju�\u0011�x\t>�+B�1%8�V.�`���h\u000ffGh@��\"�4u)⨮7Ɍ�飿����\u0010cd5�E�J0�\u00132��\u0010\u000b)$�\u001d��f��lg��A�\u0018�\u000f\n[\u0011��12\u0005���\u000b*��}\u0006��\u0011����o��^|:~^�D���4/��~Y���FP)\r��V�,�\t~#\r�'��a�,�͚�9~\u0016�\u001c���#�ZQ�T�ErK�)\u0010ɖ�.�C\u0004��͖�\u001a���P?���{��2T(�'A\r}�M!EU>\u0002�>�z���ћ>�\u001eeR\u001aq�S18^�fr6�\u0000fa�i\u001fa�jӱ�\u0016�5R>cU�N��|�V9��\u0005t=?e�MIpx�1N\u000e��O�\u0012�\u0000N���w��m��\u001bΆ�\u0000�<�o�e�`޷G�T}\u000b\u0016\u0017�\u0013�\u00127U�\f#\f\"{\u0016�q�+`-\u000fI`�\u000eD�8\u001c���<�\u001cE��Ʉ��7��c��?UU\u0006�@��>\u001e�����*�6k�\u000f�Qi�����?��\\����p�\u0002r�ރoR��E\"����TE�\u0004�i�P�\f�\u001aj���k��$84�ʻd\u0002�ڄ�+c|6\u0015g���aÐ��\u0011��0���[(v&x�E�]ۣ!�_y��z\u001eI�~Gn\u000f���c_;\u001a�\u001cD��h\t�n����<��RWH�9B�!Xׂ�\u001f\u001a\u001eCA�����\t�W*�\u0013b�Md�@%NV�\n�a�\u001a\b�84K���>c�`,��?e�z^���O�1fY��~�\u00009ʩ\u0010���\u001c\t͑�a�h�\u0007G�\u0000u�My\u0002,\u001f5�]�52�(�K�\u001fي�H��\u001f�V�C\u001c�\n���L_#\\\f�V�]�d�'lf�\u001d�>\\�x\u0015�\u001f�^+�G8-v�hz*C<��1j4����0�_�ɇ~W����=|\u0017��Q\u001c��ϒ�h���>�O��m�\f�X�\u0012\u001b�1�?~=��\u001b{,��[^��1\r�\u001a��̿\f��F�\u0011�#\u0016˳��,�t�u�a�s�5�Ǡ\u0016�E��\n�o\u000f\u0001v�W6?\u000b��a�W��O�:\u001d&X\u0019\u0014Nd� 9�-\u0016m���q}-i�Q\\\u0015��\u0017\u0013�[C�I\u0004\u0007Q�.]Jg3�\n8��\u0019�����__�NYN�n3�2#��A��[\u0019+03�\u001c�=ُx�K'c�\n�@\u0000Ih�f�\t\u0015�����\u000b\n��\b�8h\u0012��\u0011F�����\u000b� \u0015L�>\u0018\u0001��{�\n\u001eeS\u001cj�|\u001c7!\u000e\"u�\u0012�`\u0019���\u001f��+\u0000�\u000f�IV\u001a\fd\bm:�\u000f�@��\\ٚ4=������=\u0002\u0015G�z&��/�(ĽV'�7g\"���\r\u0010l\u001f\u0010�Q���M?#k�b\u0019���\u001ah�v�xk�\nYU\":\u001c��\u001c����Rh���c\u0004�\u0001V9�Q�\u001an���+\\(��H�7�Lk��\u0012r��ܨ5\\\u0005�j±\u0018X�c��\u0002ߡ�GB�\u0014�9�te�a�\\mIZg��d�<N[�F�k��Nބ4_C\t,�����N\u0007�#��\u0000\u0011�h�\"F5�g4\u001f+Y6ӣ3.�ȸ�\u0019�\u0003�r��ǣA'�\"��B���\u000fN\u001d]��\u0000\u0016�t�\u001d<��\u0015\t1�\u001c+\r\u0013�B�\u000fS�f�\u0000�ܫ,0�|�X�b��\u0019�45�\u0006�Z\u0000\u0003MI\u0003�}�\u0014Q�7��%7�.�`m^��,�Q��\u001ce�$�ӧ!�\u0002���\u0017Ɍ�_�$��Y����Y\u001b��E7�қ��7\u001c�\"fFI� m<\"��\t#%��^ZG5V�(j`��?�~9�rC�\u001f�S��f�\u0007\n���8�E1Yx�U2l����(\u0006&JN��\u000e).X��n�\u001f��N�*4V�s=4�h�\u0012�1+:��P��Q\u001ba�(4vii+\u000e�G\u0013c^��\u0000Zw\u0005NEqJP��_'�x�\u000b0H[�\\-��q������m6�g��>EN\n�\u001e�\u0007:H��+^\b\u0005��_N\fɮ��k�ŞK\u0016X�N���\nv���x\u0015\u0016�c\u001c�\u0018�\u0000�?U6���C^\u001f8\"�N�My��V����J!-�l6�����\fn �`u�\u0014�\u0014�cI�\u0010�[���f|�ox}���\u0016�\u0006g��.�#�}?��\u0013\u001f�^=׷�{�N\u0015�\u0000��۵�evXk���s\u000f�z\u001c��NX�v|����l?��H�G<�F�i���\u0005zڢ�\u0004&�\u0012x�b�\u00065�$��\u0006Z\u0002�y���(��Ax�����4\u0000ߘ\u001c�K �\u0019\\�N'WP5]ytR�C���\u0012�\\w�\u0014^S���if �\u0019>5M�'E'6��\u001f`�\u0011�f�7�\u0000\"?$�خC�/\u0006�?�1}]�>�\r�؍���H�8_�ff�ଇ�f*.\u0003'mt\u0003nѧe��l`\u0000\u0007D�$��\f+͔�c�4jv#\u0018��Ɉ˩Q1YD���Y�m��k�R<����Ko#�@hWj�y�����\r\tC\f#\u0014�\u0000�\u000b\nJ\u00181\u0010\u0014��VR�ezW\u0013�\u0001�<-��Xt;���r*t�/�<�Or������\t�<�FӇ��\u0007�Z\"ϣ�H��>\u0019g\u0007��/�ZH\"�\u0006��A�+ԧ2�0����yƸk1\u0011I�����t���ƌ�>�\u000f��W6�i�2�X���`�'��r\u0012��PT\\,��q�\f c/���F�f��U���ؙ�\u000e^ͯ�]-�7\\���s��\\�r��ͪ�\u001c8�Wo����\u000f���$�K+G��\u0000����f��6V�ZLx��;��\\�Vؽ��_����\u0014\u0019�\u000246\u000e��\u0017�RS�y�[���Ρgs`����t�/\u0007P�\u0015ċ�\u000bГ����S\u001c�x�֓].�� ��X\u001bK�^�\u000f3�����l�\u0000�����3��'�\u0001�#�5�I$�Њ�я��F���\u0006�6�h��#A��dh�*t��C@�5\u001c\u0003,ɐ��\u0012\u0013XM\u000e\u000e\u0015���li\u0004IP�68ӡY�\u0002�\u0016�1/TGP��9���\u000b�����e �2\\C\u0018\t�jϩ$�\u0000W�\u001d�&�b ���z���x%lF7�E{\u0002|��\u0002C\u0016�.�hz\"�B\t\u001d@SJ�dR�Z\u0014:\t�\u0014�\u000b\"�5���h�\u000fm�=Aݧ��h�mT�>:g�8�\u0004�\u000e㙦���G%��g��S\f��W˜�\u0013�xewt�ו�v�k����Z\u000fɇX���~�y�\u0012����t�p.e9���z�4,�,�Z��\u001c�!-nJ5?�!�5�l,k�5kNmN�\n\u0003̟D�D>,�2lo�>\u0019��H,�>K��9������z�j{#\u0013���%W�?\u0012�\u0012��f\u0003(?h\u000b�\u000eut�ϒv�8�7��bM����,�\u0010�n><���\u0005A���\u0015���Y\u001aCM\u001a6A�\u000b>i��\u0013�����>6�3\u001f���\u001b,��Y\u0017�L5�\u001c����\t\u0015�!�kdVLr]��\u0019\u0012��'H%nŢ\u0012��]h�\u000e�����\u0012\u0015��\u0006.\bn\r��e`�,ٖ�Qh>\u0017(U\u001c\u0019\u001b\u001d���=ʴ0�]!J�Ok\u001b�G����w=\u0007]�Ҵ�J��9!4�W\fZ���\\\rP�7CG�F�칬0��\u001a��\b8�Aw�Z\u0001�\u0006g\u0013[\u0002\\u�\t!�Ƥ�\f�>���5ז6\u000b��\u001a��\u0000j\u000e���\u00195�k�;�$�\u0010�?�Oj����\u0001kC\u001bWuVH�D\f�]/�v79c��ѫ\u0014!��lk���\u0019\u001a�no!��\u0000��5�\u001eK�US섻쵲5��n\u000e�CGW�N��<o�$��(\u0005���\u001f J��I�[`�\u0013��W��~X��,��kz���z���\u001fТ�cZ�G�����\u001c\r���ܘS'p�-8�\u0018�:��\u0011���\u001d���lg\u0010�F\u000b\u001e��-jX��\u0010ܝ�B�/�r�I<��Il-�e�-��A�j�\u001aH��I��=\u0004.ö3��\b܀u<�y������\u000f\u001b�C�I�uު�~{$s:���qĒ\u000f��O;�)���b��\u0013��<��0���s�F�#[�/\u000b��)�jƄw:\u0010�,C���\u000006�q��ro�,Qݏ���\u000f�1ݲ�U�\\\u000e�\u0011֩8Upx�$�ּ/\u0019�#dD����X�\u0015�\u0004�Qe\u001a��1V�P�D<�|Q쵀���XC#I,�$Z��\u0014J��ΰ'7Tw�͟\u0011�� \u001a�d>\u001a}\u0016�\u001c;vY6�0�\u0011:��\u0011'�#O�w�ˎ\u001c��xߐn!�Ƽ\u0017=�\u0000��H&��\u001a,ٵ��\u0000�\u0004��&v ������Q��d�7�;9�;\u001d\u001f\u0003���/�&�ss\u000eW]w�Ь�|�#D��н�G���qv�C^\u0005-������\u0000P��\u0003�\r��Ӫ��G\u0018*�a��\u000b��\n+�\u0000�\u001cG2KG���x\u0014�e�m/�U�.��\u0018�\u0017\b�67��klr �I4��K�7���h/��Re����u\u0019�]�\u000f\"<\nx���q\u0018 4;V�[4Q��,��Ѻ#5G�.�G�\u0000\u0013�/?&����\n��\b�M6,�47���,Yt����Co~Kd!��ui�m~�K\u001c�):�[��v\u001f鵂� 4k��ií�\tZ�F\u0017+쳉qW?5X�\u0006�:�|���\u0000�'��_��\u0000\u0000���Y,�_ nS`\u000e��\u0011GQ��K7�B.���\u0006㇁����}\u0005{\u0005�z�F�����P8C��������f-f,���\r�g\fûb����N>\u0018j����\u000b�\u0018\u0012F@\u000e�ė\u0016}�\u000fC�\f�\u0006\\r�\\{��\u001bY,/�\u0014��\b9�p\u0000�q繣�9N��K��a�]H���\u001b�\u000b\u0014l\u001e��Lßn�<\u0003��v�4�5\u001d|BǓ\u0006��F9†2F���-���3��\u00192��ы��0�nhd��\u0012�k\n�%U��\tlk����\u001a�g\u0014\u0018�Mb��:\u001b�\u0016��?��\u0007�Y�'UG��zx�F+�7�����Ts��\u000emC��(�\u001d\u0003�=\u0001&�\u00144�`�]��)�П��\u0011��u�z>J��S��%�\u0004r&�\"�u\u0000�\u0000<\u0012G-vv���#�O�~��\u0012-\u001d�\u0004a�.лk�9r;��I�g$.�|K+�\u001b@�5���kQ�\u001bt�|sJS�\u0005�\u001a��ks\u000ex���u��\u001a!����!�\r�7��\u0014kCZ\u0013{R�$�f\u001df�0[�=��_\u001a�x�\u0019���Ϙ\u000f���!'\u0016�^�X��b�x��_��F�5�c�T�SU\"��f�Xat`��s\u0016�\u0003��y��w\u0007-�X ��TRvf�v-�ҽ����\u0018Ѣ?�k\u0000�s�Rm>\u0006�|O�3�ZƁZ�#s��u�.�\u0004��Bm@�q�\u001d\b#�i��/6�o]\b�E�\u0016�����,�\tx@��7{>�\u0000�\u001b+���mh��R�v�9\u0010v7��%�\u0010@嘸�\u0000���Y%\u001f �ˡ$\n�\u000f��+,��,*m\u0010\u0019`\u000f~\\�,N\u0001Ѹ]�]�\u001b��-�=l�=�_�Ԣ�}�<K�\\쀆��\u000e�:Y��U��+>!м9�ch��_��~\u0003ř�f�\u001e\u0007x~af�\b�42t\u000b&\\6!Ʋ��<n/��{\u0002���$�Sl\r�2$�!-sQ��\u001e�\u0014�{�\\�\u0002�\u001a����>6��ѳ����!oÅ8�n����x7@�\u0000�\u0000Nn�\u0000ϩ��-.\u0019��\u0017>YUl��qPF;����w��z]:���\u0000����E�8�r ��qv�7�o� lT�ka�\u0012u�>�\u0000a�\u001f\"|d]��\u0002�\u0011`\u001dj���7����/�\u0019��ۋZ@\"Àԃ���������Ƿ�A�\u0000cl��v�����[��\u001e{!$�1��\u0001���@\bl�\u0002�@�\"��+n)��z:\\�\u0005\u0017��G�\u000b\u001c\u000f.cꩱ1�'\u0017����m�V�g,��>�x{D29�ݒ�;\u0002F�kJ¢��y�x1\u000f��1����_D��i\u0000?\u0012\u0005�:�s��Qy\u0004\u00048�\t\u0001ץ_29_�G�\u0005.��\u0012}N��\u0012���0p4�\u0002\r\u001d�\u001a�}킆l�0m5k��t\u001d�\r\u0000��9;d[#�2u��p�ݳ�^��.�4��\u0011\u0014jr��q\r6\u0007 =�h�|�w�Z��|E�\f`�\u001f��s\u001f������Xc+��6KЭ�\fO\t��\u0007��H#��A�!Z>���\u001bn)��{~a��,�\"�)†�e�\u0013\u0010�%,3��C�q�\u0004�!\"ET�=�\u0006:.b[\t`bV�w�R8�ˆ��wK\u001b\fr�'!�\u0006�y\\�:Y�#��Qc\u001c�\u001by��uM�\u0012�E\u0017бV�~\u001dô\u0012�3[ή;���䫟&9Mc�{{�7�\u001a��C\b��_=��:\fPjqdl\\�\f\u0003ͽ��m\f�\u001bf.��<M�\u0019\\s�W��(+E�&\u0019����w\u0005f&3\u0014�����A�A�|RaY\u001c�D<[Nѕ�\u001f�����ud{C�ڲ�@�{�YB{yj����J��\u0015��8�!`�X\u001a�\u001c�:BX4%�wgN���\\t#�'|�&�|F�\u0002������C.Oq\f�&r㹥�d���'\r�O�\u0012.�a�S�g]!�\u0017���#���y�u�|AP�~��\u0016�Ph��n�<�}�D�rJ8���ʉ�\u0005\u0015�g�T���)�u���Z��&Y�#�\u000b\u0018č�\u001b���\u0000)պ\u001e1�G��\u001ah-���[5W\u00018\f8{i�\u0010y\u0015�\u0014\u001ffK\u0011q��Z�3��Ɠ�~��GS(*|���?�|?\u0003\"\u0011\u0018���0\u0006ʗ�rv�rl#��8 %��\u0018]�_�S{b�6�%�HĢ��9 �\rP�0��\u0014\u0014hdX’\\\u0014Aq\u0004�!,j\f\u0005��(�0�\u0005�����\t�K���M,oH�6SiKp��Nhv�P\u000e�b�\u001c\u0014\u001d�w]\u0013��h\u0002L���\u0014��T���<\u001a\u0005SO�\u001ci3�S!ŻW48\n{;�x�Ԃ9��hé�,�\u000e+�t\u0015>\u0006�\u0007\u001c��ҳ0҉\u0015��/YWc��\u0017�8�V\u0018�Q9\u0006�\u0001�ʗ\u0001H��N6�<8;K�Gm:)��\u0019�N*�<��%fy������\u0000в��J�9�\u001c\u000f\u0007h#��\u0013�l?U\u0007��\u0016�m�\u0012�l�`0��)k��\f�.��5丒/��\"��/>�t\u000b��0�{�)e��\u0005l\u0016���D5o�j)a��\u0000\u0006\"`�����o�\u0000'�\u0018��\u001f����]\u001c\u0013�s_�9I�Ȃ��A\u0007\u0004�\u0000�J_�?a�I\u0015:\u0017t>�\u0005\t?\fZax*m���Qb�_&�x�cl\u001al.wZՇ\u0007�d�.F�8����\u0014�\u001d�\u0012��c#�L��0C\\�\u0019\u001cy�\u0000y\u0002\u0014qM���y�l\t �8\u000e�LEE�k\nc�8�O�KG\u000bیi;R0�\u0018�0�\u0001☒[��ϒ\u0019ujn�,��\b��ed��,��\u0007�/��W\u001c�\u0003j��\u0016�>\te�ȿ���卍�M��]E�rŦ����\u0006-��^�\u001d\u001a4\u001e\u001e����Ri�|}B�Cư�����/�@:l@5��<^�����T\u001f�9&\u001aR쵩4\u0000\"�:/BS���OE)\u001b���cz�_D\\�ag|2\u0000��\u0011v:lU#\u0018jq�(?�\u001a�\u001b\u0011�@\u0007�=\u0002�q�q�^Ĕ]��|X��B����hz�ˊ\u0019� f�\u0019j����s{��\\\u0018\u0017;��\u001fu�\u000e�Y\u001e�����'�q�\n\u0001o�\u0018�\u001am�G����A\\�%=;�3�a\\]JS�\tci���0\u0014\\,x�\u001b����ݥT�(���t�\u001ah�\u0014�`�$�H�\u0017&JT3da^\u00110�d�u5V\\ \b昗R�r\\�Hd5³KV�*V�eΕ,�\u0005\u0013d��0�yW���TH\u00043�@.��%\u0010���f�GD��\u001a\t,�v���
```

I am using Angular 10 on the client side.  I call back to a NodeJS layer I have coded and the Node layer calls the REST endpoint in question.  I have tried:

- Sending the stream directly to the HTML image tag,
- Prepending a media type tag to the stream and sending to the media tag along with the stream to the browser, e.g. "data:image/jpeg;Base64," + binary data as well as "data:image/jpeg," + binary data,
- I have used atob() and sent this result along with the media type to the browser,
- I have encased the local image variable in the DOMSanitizer() like this...`this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`data:image/jpg, ${binaryData}`)` and `this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`data:image/jpg;Base64, ${binaryData}`)`,
- I have tried everything I have read and sit sleepless unable to understand why something seemingly so simple is hitting me in such a perplexed manner.

Here is the HTML tag I am using...

```
<div>
    <p>Here is the user image</p>
    <img [src]="imageName">
</div>
```

What else can I provide?  Boy, any assistance will sure be appreciated.

***** UPDATE

Really, it comes down to this...How to convert a byte array into something that can be displayed on the Browser as an image.  I think converting this to Base64 is the way to go.  I have tried playing with the NodeJS buffer and haven't cracked it, yet.

**** UPDATE (Adding Code)

Here are two more code components.  As mentioned, this isn't really a client-side, Angular, browser issue.  This is really just a data conversion issue.  How to take a byte array response to a rest call and turn that into something the browser can display.  I am assuming the data should be converted into a Base64 representation.  I have tried a couple approaches to perform this conversation but to no success.  Once again, I stand baffled why this seems so difficult.  I have to be missing something easy.

The two code segments I am including are both from my node layer.  My node layer consists, by and large, of two component types: routers and apis.  The routers handle rest calls from the angular layer and pass those calls unto the api components, which route the call to my partner's Java back-end.

Here are the code components.  You can see in the commented out code the various things I tried to correctly convert the data.

Here is the router...

```
//Route to get user photo
router.get('/:userId/photo', validateAuthorization, (req, res) => {
try {

        logger.logIt(configSettings.logFileName, 'In userRoutes - In userRoutes - Get User Photo - ' + req.params.userId);
        var emWebResponse = new EMWebResponse();

        (async () => {  
            try {
                var response = await userApi.getPhoto(req.params.userId);
            
                emWebResponse.statusCode = response.statusCode;
                emWebResponse.statusMessage = response.statusMesssage;

                var bufferString = new Buffer.from(response.body).toString()
                //console.log("HERE IS THE RAW DATA - ", response.body);
                //console.log("HERE IS THE BUFF RESULTS - ", new Buffer.from(response.body).toString());
                console.log("btoa - ", btoa(bufferString));
                console.log("atob - ", atob(bufferString));

                emWebResponse.body = response.body;  
                //buffer = new Buffer();
                //buffer(userPhotoResponse.body).toString('ascii');
                //userModel.image = btoa(userPhotoResponse.body);
                //var byteArray = Buffer.from(response.body, 'hex');
                res.send(emWebResponse); 
            } catch (error) {
                logger.logIt(configSettings.logFileName, '*****Inner Error***** - In userRoutes - Get User Photo - ' + error);
                emWebResponse.statusCode = error.statusCode;
                emWebResponse.statusMessage = error.statusMessage;
                emWebResponse.body = '';
                res.send(emWebResponse);
            }
        })();  
    }
    catch (error) { 
        logger.logIt(configSettings.logFileName, '*****Outer ERROR***** - In userRoutes - Get User Photo - ' + error); 
        return (error);            
    }
});
```

Here is the api...

```
    module.exports.getPhoto = function (userId) {  

    logger.logIt(configSettings.logFileName, 'In userApi - Get Photo - ' + userId);

    try {

        var bearerValue = 'Bearer ' + userSecurityToken.access_token;

        const options = {
            hostname: 'localhost',
            protocol: 'http:',
            port: '8888',
            path: configSettings.baseUrl + '/users/' + userId + '/photo',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': bearerValue,
                'Cache-Control':'no-cache'
            }
        };

        return got(options);

    } catch (error) {
        logger.logIt(configSettings.logFileName, '*****ERROR***** In userApi - Get Photo - ' + error);
    }
}
```

***** UPDATE - July 8, 2020 - New Code Segments as per Hanan and Myerffoeg recommendations.

API Segment with the reponseType header...

```
GetUserPhotoObservable(userId: string): Observable<EMWebResponse> {

    this.logService.log(LogLevel.debug, "In userAPI - Get User Photo - " + userId);

    let httpOptions = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', "application/json")
        .set('Cache-Control', "no-cache")
        .set('responseType', 'blob' as 'json');

    let httpParams = new HttpParams()
        .set('Authorization', "Bearer " + this.securityTokenModel.access_token)

    try {

      return this.http.get<EMWebResponse>(this.configFileModel.baseUrl + "/users/" + userId + "/photo", 
              {headers: httpOptions, 
              params: httpParams});
    }
    catch (e) {
      this.logService.log(LogLevel.error, "In userAPI, Get User Photo - Error Occurred - " + e);
    }
  }
```

Manager code using the FileReader

```
private GetUserPhotoComplete(emWebResponse) {

    var userImage = new Blob([emWebResponse.body], {type: "image/jpeg"});
    console.log("THIS IS THE BLOB - ", userImage);
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      var b64 = fileReader.result;
      console.log("FILEREADER.ONLOAD, This is what we got - ", b64);
    } 

    console.log("ABOUT TO LOAD");
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(userImage);
}
```

Comment: What is your HTTP call (code) from Angular to get this image ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your interest and sorry for the delay.  I am providing two chunks of code.  Both of these chunks are on my Node side.  What I realized is that this isn't an Angular or a client-side (browser) issue at all.  It is really a data conversion issue. 

As mentioned above, I have a client-side layer using Angular 10 and a server-side component using Node.  My server-side consists, by and large, of two component types, routers and apis.  The routers receive the request from Angular and pass the request to the api components, which call downstream of my partners Java layer.

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I am having the same problem and need help

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for base64 encoding
While using Base64 urls u have to sanitize it while assigning to image.src like this

```
<img [src]="snaitizar.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageData)">
```

if u want solution for just binary then u have to first convert ur **binary string** to base64 using btao and then use upper solution like this

```
<img [src]="snaitizar.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(btoa(imageData))">
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this response.  I have have two questions: 

1) Is the red bar intended to block something out or highlight something, because I cannot see anything in the red.

2) What is the data type the endpoint is returning?  Remember, my endpoint is returning binary, not Base64.

You are showing something new to me.  I will try these things.

Comment: 1- I m hiding any Security key behind red line.
2-  json with some which has base64 string
I have updated my ans please check and ask more question I will improve it

Comment: Cool - Thank you very much for your help.  These techniques did not help.  Really, it comes down to this - I am receiving a byte array.  I have to convert this to Base64 or something that will display on the Browser as an image.  Again, it is extremely perplexing to me why this is an issue.  I am playing with a buffer in Node, right now.  No luck, yet.

Comment: I did not know u are reviving byte array to this solution work on byte string 
u can convert ur byte array to byte string

what are u using on ur backend ? can u simply convert binary array to base64 str ?

Comment: I have tried and can't seem to convert is - it is perplexing.  I can pull an image via Postman and it looks just fine, but when I pull it from my Node layer and try performing the conversion, I cannot get a Base64 result that renders an image.  There is a cool website that will convert a Base64 encoding into the image.  I have been using that website to validate my conversion but nothing I have tried works.  It should be easy, right?  AHH!

Comment: on server convert text to binary and then convert back to string on client.

Comment: As said by Hanan send a binary of the image & on the Angular side use the responseType "Blob" `responseType = 'blob' as 'json'` to get it as a Blob then use the FileReader API with readAsDataURL to get a base64 data url. If you have any trouble I'll post an answer about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.  I copied the new code above.  I did find something interesting, though.  I found a website: https://base64.softbaba.com/string-to-byte-array-online.php#done.  If I use my original Base64 image and "decode" it on this site, it is exactly like the byte array I am trying to convert.  Then I copy that result, paste it into the first input box and Encode it.  I get the same result I am getting from my code, it doesn't equal the original Base64 data and is not a displayable image.  Is the Decoding adding some data that needs to be stripped?

Comment: Try to use FileReader API with readAsDataURL to get a base64 data url, using btoa just gives you a b64 encoded string but you want a data url.

Comment: @Myerffoeg - I am not sure I understand.  The code segments I copied above under the ***** UPDATE - July 8, 2020 shows in my manager class I am using fileReader.readAsDataURL(userImage), the userImage being a new Blob I created from the data returned by the Rest call.  This is what I thought you recommended in your first response.  Do you see something off in this latest code segment?  The one thing I am not sure about is the "type" parameter when creating the Blob.  I am going to read up a bit on that.  I TRULY appreciate your continued assistance.

Answer (score 0):

To get a dataUrl you should first retrieve your Blob with the Angular's HttpClient. But here you get a Blob that could be anything but you want a data url to display it in a `img` tag so you have to convert it & for that we'll use the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API (with RxJS since readAsDataURL is async & we want it to be wrap around Observables).

```
// RxJS way to convert a Blob to a string (data url) since readAsDataURL is async
readAsDataURL(blob: Blob): Observable<string> {
  return new Observable((obs: Observer<string>) => {
   const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

   reader.onerror = err => obs.error(err);
   reader.onabort = err => obs.error(err);
   reader.onload = () => obs.next(reader.result as string);
   reader.onloadend = () => obs.complete();

   return reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
 });
}
```

Then you can get your result as such in a `Component` :

```
this.httpClient.get(`${url}`, {
  headers: {},
  responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
}).pipe(
  mergeMap((blob: Blob) => this.readAsDataURL(blob))
).subscribe((dataUrl: string) => {
  this.dataUrl = dataUrl;
});
```

Finally, you can display it like such :

```
<img [src]="dataUrl" alt="My amazing b64 dataUrl image."/>
```

Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gevpug) example.